# pattern matching a formula in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, string-matching

I want to do a pattern matching of variables in a formula. The **ideal solution** should be able to perform as below:
`formula <- 'variable_1+variable_2*variable_3-variable_4/variable_5 + 456'` and output should be *variable_1*, *variable_2*,*variable_3*, *variable_4*, *variable_5*.

Note: variable name can contain character, underscore (_), numbers only and operations are limited to +,-,*,/. formula may contain constants as well (like here it is 456). The output should contain only variables names and should ignore any numeric constants.

I have tried the below codes. I was only able to check for the variable name containing **only character** and minus operation (-) does not work as well.

`formula <- "variableX +variableY*VariableZ"`

`strapplyc(gsub(" ", "", format(formula), fixed = T), "-?|[a-zA-Z_]+", simplify = T, ignore.case = T)` gives below output

```
   [,1]       
[1,] "variableX"
[2,] ""         
[3,] "variableY"
[4,] ""         
[5,] "VariableZ"
```

which is correct BUT when i include minus operation (-), the `strapplyc` gives wrong results
`formula <- "variableX -variableY"`
`strapplyc(gsub(" ", "", format(formula), fixed = T), "-?|[a-zA-Z_]+", simplify = T, ignore.case = T)` gives below output

```
   [,1]       
[1,] "variableX"
[2,] "-"         
[3,] "variableY"
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me on ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `strsplit()` with some extras.

```
res <- trimws(el(strsplit(formula, "\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/")))
```

Thereafter we want those elements yielding `NA` when we try to coerce them `as.numeric()`.

```
res[is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(res)))]
# [1] "variable_1" "variable_2" "variable_3" "variable_4" "variable_5"
```

#### Data

```
formula <- 'variable_1+variable_2*variable_3-variable_4/variable_5 + 456'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```r
formula <- "variable_1+variable_2*variable_3-variable_4/variable_5"
gsub("[\\+\\*\\-\\/]", ", ", formula)
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `[` and `]` start and end a group of characters that you want to select
- `\\+` escapes the + sign, with you want to replace with ", "
- `\\*` escapes the * sign, with you want to replace with ", "
- `\\-` escapes the - sign, with you want to replace with ", "
- `\\/` escapes the / sign, with you want to replace with ", "

**Edit to reflect OP's updated request**

Another way would be just to extract your variables. The below works if you hold the format `lowercaseletters_number`for your variable name:

```r
formula <- "variable_1+variable_2*variable_3-variable_4/variable_5+34+brigadeiro_5"
paste(regmatches(formula, gregexpr("variable_[0-9]", formula))[[1]],
      collapse = ", ")
```

You can also use the `stringr` package if you want the code to look a little cleaner:

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(formula, "[a-z]*_[0-9]*")
```

Comment: Thanks @Brigadeiro. sorry to miss this: the formula can contain a number as well in the operation like ```formula <- "var_1 + var_2 + 34". And i only want output var_1, var_2